# How can I work with an undefined string size in functions in C?

Tags: c, string

I am a total beginner and not a native English speaker so please excuse my ignorance. My homework is to create a function in C that compares elements of char strings. The function is later called in main(), where it is supposed to work with concrete strings. But those strings might have a different size for each entry, so there is no sense in defining the size in the function. I need to know the size of each string, otherwise my program wouldn't know when to stop. How do I achieve that? My initial thought is to use the function sizeof(). Will that work or is the solution more complicated? Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Try to understand this code: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strcmp.c.html

Comment: `c` strings are terminated with the `NUL` character `'\0'`, so all the existing string functions work from that fact. For example [`strlen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) works by looping through the string and incrementing a count for every character it sees until it finds `'\0'`, then it stops and the count is the length.

Comment: That I indicate you in the previous message is the code of the C function strcmp.

Comment: By "concrete strings" do you mean *string literals* (i.e. `"I am a string literal"`)?

Comment: And by "char strings" do you mean something different or more specific than just "strings"?

Comment: John: No, sorry, I mean just strings of text, so your example is the exact thing I am talking about.

Comment: Yano: So is it enough if I add a condition that the cycle will continue until one of the strings hit a '\0' ? I thought there would be problems with memory if the size of the string is undefined in my function. Thank you very much.

Comment: Posting the code that you have tried would improve this question.

Answer (score 1):

sizeof operator is used to evaluate size of data type or variable measured in the number of char size storage units.
 it will not be useful in evaluating length of the string.

for that purpose you can use strlen() function of C Library (string.h).
strlen() returns the length of string without including null.

You can also write your own function for calculating length of string as follow

```
int stringlen(char str[])
{
  int len=0;
  while(str[i] != '\0')
  {
   len++;
  }
  return len;
}
```